# How to dynamically fetch dates from database table to disable dates

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I'm selling 20 cupcakes per day. I need to disable dates that have fulfilled 20 orders.  I have a database table for date and quantity sold.
How can I dynamically fetch dates from database table into
`var dates = [ ]`

```
var dates = ["20/07/2020", "21/07/2020", "22/07/2020", "23/07/2020"];

function disableDates(date) {
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);

let isDefaultDisabled = false;
if(date.getDay()===2 || date.getDay()==3 || date.getDay()==4){
isDefaultDisabled = true;
}
 return [ isDefaultDisabled && dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ];
}

$(function() {
 $("#date").datepicker({
     beforeShowDay: disableDates
 });
});
```

Comment: Do you use woocommerce ? What is the extra table, which plugin created it?